# Google Maps and Google Maps directions icon

Tags: android, google-maps, icons

I would like to use the "standard" Google Maps icon and the Google Maps direction icon as src in an `ImageButton`. When the `ImageButton` is pressed I would like to fire an `Intent` to start Google Maps. The icons I have in mind are those that appear in the following screenshot. These icons appear when you show a map using Google Maps lite mode.
I can't seem to find those or similar icons provided by Google anywhere. Is this happening because I am not supposed to use them?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the direction and map icons in android studio here

> Expand res > right click on drawables > new > Vector assets > click on
>   the button against Icon > select maps

Or you can download the svg's from [here](https://material.io/icons/)

Google encourage developers to use vector assets as they are scalable and follow material design specifications suggested by google. So it's better to use them.

If you still want to use the exact icons then you can get them [here](http://www.flaticon.com/search?word=google%20maps&license=all&color=0&stroke=0)

Comment: Thanks! The directions icon is perfectly usable from the Vector assets and meterial.io but shouldn't the Google Maps icon be downloadable from Google instead of just flaticon.com?

Comment: The google map icon is google's product icon so they might not want you to use it, instead they have provided the generic map icon as a vector asset which developers should use across all the platforms so that it can maintain the uniformity. Google provides the 'powered by Google' icon for developers and insists to display it wherever developers display data from google. You can use that if it is applicable in your case.